# PHP - Echo'ing something from a MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, connection

I think, I might need help with my PHP code...
I'm trying to echo the info in a MySQL database and it gives me the Error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /usr/local/ampps/www/php/db.php on line 18`

My code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "blabla"; //changed, connecting works
$username = "blabla";
$password = "blabla";
$database = "blabla";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "Connection success \n";
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Schueler");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) //This is line 18...
{
echo "ID: " . $data['ID'] . " Vorname: " . $data['Vorname'] . " Nachname: " . $data['Nachname'] . " Klasse: " . $data['Klasse'] . "<br>";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Would be nice if somebody could help me :)

Edit:

I fixed it using MySqli only, this is my working code now:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
  echo "Connection success  \n";
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, Vorname, Nachname FROM Schueler";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["Vorname"]. " " . $row["Nachname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Thanks for the quick advice.

Comment: seems you are not connected  to db

Comment: It says "Connection success" a line above the error as i implemented into the code so i sort of connected to the database i think.

Comment: you are using `mysqli` and then fetching array using `mysql_fetch_array`. Shouldn't these two be the same?

Comment: you are not properly connected  you are using mysqli for connection and mysql_fecth for fetching  these are two different db drivers  use mysqli only

Comment: What would be the correct code then? Im not really familiar with sql and php yet...

Answer (score -1):

You have used `mysqli` for your connection setup, then you used simple `mysql` functions to get the resultset and the fetch_array logic. You need to be uniform in this case.

I have changed the `mysql_query()` call to `mysqli_query()` call, and similarly the `mysql_fetch_array()` call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` call.

The final code becomes:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Schueler", $conn);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
echo "ID: " . $data['ID'] . " Vorname: " . $data['Vorname'] . " Nachname: " . $data['Nachname'] . " Klasse: " . $data['Klasse'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /usr/local/ampps/www/php/db.php on line 17
__________
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /usr/local/ampps/www/php/db.php on line 18
__________
This way im just ending up with another warning more.

Comment: Use the edited code, as above.